# Mysql stored procedure SQLEXCEPTION

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, sqlexception

Below is my sample query, in which 1st create new folder,2nd update count, 3rd: create new tag, 4: get new id.all query are executed in same stored procedure.in which @pFolderId is the id passed by user(in parameter),
foreign key constraint are applied on folderId of tag table, when user sends valid folderId, it executes properly & i get new tagid, but when user sends invalid folderid which is not exists in folder table, then it throws exception of foreign key. but in this case 1st,2nd query is alredy executed, 3rd query gives error. my question is how to avoid query from execution on any error on any query. 1 way is to use roolback, but when i used that it execute properly for 1 invalid folder request, but when on 2nd request it executed 1,2 query and gave error on 3rd.

```
   1: insert into folder (name)values("new");
   2: update folder set count = count + 1 where idfolder=1;
   3: insert into tag(name,folder_Id)values("dsdss",@pFolderId );
   4: SELECT last_insert_id() AS tag_id;
```

how can i achieve this, avoid execution on error.any help will be appreciated. thank you in advance.

**PROCEDURE:**

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE newClip(pFolderId VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION,SQLWARNING
    BEGIN
        SELECT SQLEXCEPTION.message;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    SET @pFolderId = pFolderId;
    START TRANSACTION;
    insert into folder (name)values("new");
    update folder set count = count + 1 where idfolder=1;
    insert into tags(name,folderId)values("dsdss",@pFolderId );
    SELECT last_insert_id()AS tag_id;
    COMMIT;
END$$
```

Comment: Can you shared the stored procedure where you tried using transaction? You can also share the DDL for the tables.

Comment: DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `newClip`(pFolderId VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION,SQLWARNING
BEGIN

 SELECT SQLEXCEPTION.message;
    ROLLBACK;
END;
SET @pFolderId = pFolderId;
START TRANSACTION;
 
 insert into folder (name)values("new");
 update folder set count = count + 1 where idfolder=1;
 insert into tags(name,folderId)values("dsdss",@pFolderId );
 SELECT last_insert_id()AS tag_id;
COMMIT;
END

Comment: I can't reproduce the exact problem without your table structure. However, `SELECT SQLEXCEPTION.message;` produces an error on my side. 

Can you test without it?